# Twig+ Wordpress - How to pass array arguments to function?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, symfony, twig

I'm using a Wordpress theme that was developed using Twig template system. I don't know anything about Twig an don't have the time to learn it.

So my question is, in Wordpress we can use `get_terms()` to get all the terms from a taxonomy but we can *filter* the terms we want to receive using an `array` of arguments that is the second parameter to the function.

That being said, I have a line in a twig file that goes like this:

```
{% for distrito in wp.get_terms('Distritos') %}
```

`distrito` is my `variable` and `Distritos` is my taxonomy name. This works, it calls all of the terms, but I want to use the `array` arguments so that I can get only the root elements since my taxonomy has hierarchy.

I understand that I must have somewhere the place where wp.get_terms is defined but I can't find it.

Comment: I think you have to find out how it is implemented... Maybe using a plugin? Or by hand? How are templates being rendered? Seems like you're going to have to learn Twig after all...

Comment: hi, thanks for the sugestion but the thing is,even twig itself doesn't have specific tutorials on getting it together with wordpress. I'm hopping someone can show me the direction, only that.

Comment: Well, Twig is just a templating engine. It does need some glue to make it work with WordPress seamlessly but it doesn't have any dependencies. So you'd have to find the glue to understand how it's working on that particular theme... Maybe it's using this plugin https://github.com/jarednova/timber/?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Twig works more or less like plain PHP. For a function call you add *parameters* like you would in PHP:

```
{{ method(parameter1, parameter2) }}
```

Arrays can be defines using `[` and `]`. Also associative arrays can be defined using `{` and `}` like this:

```
{% set array = [1, 2, 3] %}
{% set assoc = {'key': 'value', 'key2': 2} %}
```

So your function call should look something like this:

```
{% for distrito in wp.get_terms('Distritos', ['a', 'b', 'c']) %}
```

Checkout the twig docs for [further information](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#setting-variables).

Comment: one more thing, if i want to take each value from this get_terms and get the next level on the same taxonomy i do that, in wordpress by passing the id of parent term to get child. How can i achieve that with twig?